# Date picker libraries are missing in specific page

Tags: 8

I am adding jquery date picker feature using date field in profile edit page it is working fine .

But when i am adding same jquery datepicker in custom module, datepicker function is not working.

After seeing view page source i have found these three libraries are including in profile edit page where date picker is working.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/core/assets/vendor/jquery.ui/themes/base/datepicker.css?q7wdca" media="all" />
<script src="/core/assets/vendor/jquery.ui/ui/widgets/datepicker-min.js?v=1.12.1"></script>
<script src="/core/modules/locale/locale.datepicker.js?v=8.6.15"></script>
```

But i am not able to figure out why these libraries are not including in custom form page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have a custom theme? If so, the easiest way to ensure `jquery.ui.datepicker` loads on every page is to list it as a dependency in your theme libraries file. E.g.

```
# @file /themes/custom/my_theme/my_theme.libraries.yml

# My theme global library.
global:
  js:
    js/my_theme.js: {}
  css:
    theme:
      css/my_theme.css: {}
  dependencies:
    - core/jquery
    - ...
    - core/jquery.ui.datepicker
```

Alternatively, you can add it via a theme or custom module.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_page().
 */
function my_theme_or_module_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  $variables['#attached']['library'][] = 'core/drupal.date';
}
```